# How to keep ruby on rails script running persistently within rails app on ec2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I have deployed the Ruby on Rails 3 version application on EC2 using Passenger Standalone version. In my application I have a Mailman script which checks for the emails for every 60 seconds & add the email contents in rails database. Whenever I run the script "script/mailman_server" on my ec2 AMI it fetches the emails from designated email address.I want the mailman script should persistently fetch the emails with out manual intervention i.e I don't want to run the script manually each time to get the emails.
It is very well handled in heroku but not sure how it works on the EC2..any help!!! :)

Comment: What is your question? Can you also post some code to look at as well?

Comment: I am trying to keep mailman server script running on the AWS EC2. same as any background job which keeps on running. Sorry but there is no as such code which I can share in the post.

Comment: basically I want to make a daemon process on ec2 which runs mailman script at backend